# Mustache Js: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: php, jquery, mustache, mustache.php

1. This is my template

---

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
    {{#displayprd}}  
    <div class="w-dyn-item w-col w-col-4 re-thumb" >
    <a class="w-inline-block re-thumb-items modal-link">
    <div class="reward-image thumb"><img class="re-thumb-image">
    </div>
    <div class="r-item-name">{{product_name}}</div>
    <div class="r-points thumb">ddd</div>
    </a>
    </div>
    {{/displayprd}}
    </script>
```

2. Templating rendering part

---

```
var template = Mustache.compile($.trim($("#template").html()));
  var view = function(movies){
    return template(movies);
  };
```

3. While looping with mustache below I am getting the following error, what does it mean and how do I solve it !?!?!

---

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="w-dyn-item w-col w-col-4 re-thumb" >
                  <a class="w-inline-block re-thumb-items modal-link">
                    <div class="reward-image thumb"><img class="re-thumb-image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="r-item-name">2KG BLACK FOREST CAKE</div>
                    <div class="r-points thumb"></div>
                  </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you try changing the type of the script to `text/javascript`?

Comment: tried getting same error !!!!!!

Comment: Please include the code you are using to render the template.

Comment: _That_ does not look like the code used to render the template.